# Reedy model structures on oplax limits

Tags: model-categories, at.algebraic-topology, reference-request

Suppose $R$ is a category and $F:R\to Cat$ is a functor (or pseudofunctor).  The *oplax limit* of $F$ is the category whose objects consist of an object $x_r \in F(r)$ for all $r$ together with a morphism $x_s \to F(d)(x_{r})$ for all morphisms $d:r\to s$ in $R$, satisfying obvious compatibility conditions.

I have some vague memory of reading a paper in which, given a functor as above in which $R$ is a Reedy category, each category $F(r)$ is a model category, and probably some other conditions, a "Reedy-type" model structure on the oplax limit (or perhaps some related category) was constructed.  However, I have been totally unable to find this paper again; the closest I can find is [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.0717) which considers "injective-type" model structures on lax limits.  Can anyone point me to the paper I am thinking of?

(I am not interested in seeing proofs or "it seems like this should work" arguments written out in the answers.  I only want the reference.)

Comment: How does having a morphism $x_r \to F(d)(x_s)$ work (typecheck)?  Isn't $F(d)$ a functor *from* $F(r)$ *to* $F(s)$, while $x_s$ is an object in $F(s)$?

Comment: Thanks, fixed.  (Sometimes people talk about contravariant functors instead of covariant ones.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the paper I was thinking of when I asked this question was probably

- Markus Spitzweck, [Homotopy limits of model categories over inverse index categories](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jpaa.2009.08.001), JPAA 214:6 (2010)

although he only considers the case of inverse categories rather than more general Reedy ones.  A more recent reference that does deal with the case of general Reedy categories is

- Edouard Balzin, Reedy Model Structures in Families, [arXiv:1803.00681](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.00681)

I have collected some more remarks and references on model structures of this sort at the nLab page [model structure on sections](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/model+structure+on+sections).

Answer (score 5):

You may be thinking of

Johnson, Mark W. *On modified Reedy and modified projective model structures.*
Theory Appl. Categ. 24 (2010), No. 8, 179–208.

but his constructions (Definitions 3.3 and 5.2) have a fixed category at each object of $R$ and only the model structures are allowed to vary.

As a side note, a particular instance of this construction is used in these [new notes](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/schwede/global.pdf) about global homotopy theory, but here the indexing category is not even a Reedy category, but some sort of "enriched generalized Reedy category".

Comment: I don't think that was the paper I'm thinking of, but thanks for pointing it out; it's certainly closely related!