# Explicit description of the oplax limit of a functor to Cat?

Tags: ct.category-theory, limits-and-colimits

The [nCatLab Grothendieck construction page](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+construction#definition_10) gives an explicit description of the oplax colimit of any functor to Cat.  Can someone give me a similarly explicit description (the objects and morphisms) of an oplax limit of any functor to Cat (or a link to a page which describes it)?  (I've found [Reedy model structures on oplax limits](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120382/reedy-model-structures-on-oplax-limits), but that leaves unspecified the "'obvious' coherence conditions".)

Additionally, is there a name for such a category, analogous to "Grothendieck construction" or "category of elements"?

Context: The reason I'm interested in this is because I'm trying to formulate the categorical dependent sum and dependent product in Coq.  I think the oplax (co)limit are the dependent sum/product pushed across a Yoneda-like transformation (though I'm not entirely sure that it's Yoneda).  Coq's dependent sum and product are more similar to the oplax (co)limit formulation, and while nCatLab has good pages on [dependent sum](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dependent+sum) and [dependent product](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dependent+product), it doesn't seem to have such a page on oplax limits.

**Edit:** I'm looking for a description of the objects and morphisms in this category, possibly together with the composition law.  Here is my guess at what the objects and morphisms are:  Given a functor $F : \mathcal C \to \text{Cat}$, and letting $F_0$ denote its action on objects and $F_1$ denote its action on morphisms,

- *Objects* consist of the following components

  - For each object $r \in \mathcal C$, an object $x_r \in F_0(r)$
  - For all objects $s, d \in \mathcal C$ and each morphism $m \in \text{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(s, d)$, a morphism $f_m \in \text{Hom}_{F_0(d)}((F_1(m))_0(x_s), x_d)$ (Note: This doesn't agree with [Reedy model structures on oplax limits](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120382/reedy-model-structures-on-oplax-limits), but I can't figure out how to typecheck what's there; I've added a comment to that effect.)
  - For all $r \in \mathcal C$, a proof that $f_{\text{id}_r} = \text{id}_{x_r}$ (well, actually, that $f_{\text{id}_r}$ is equal to the isomorphism induced by the proof that $(F_1(\text{id}_r))_0(x_r) = x_r$)
  - For all $p, q, r \in \mathcal C$ and all morphisms $m_0 \in \text{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(q, r)$ and $m_1 \in \text{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(p, q)$, a proof that $f_{m_0 \circ m_1} = (F_1(m_1))_1(f_{m_0}) \circ f_{m_1}$
- *Morphisms* from $(x, f)$ to $(x', f')$ consist of the following components:

  - For each object $r \in \mathcal C$, a functor $g_r : x_r \to x'_r$.
  - Some coherence condition I haven't managed to phrase yet, corresponding to the commutativity square for natural transformations.

Did I get anything wrong?  (In particular, is the second component of objects right?  Also, what changes for lax vs. oplax?)

Comment: Are you familiar with the construction of a weak limit? The oplax case is the same, but you just have to be careful with the directions of the arrows.

Comment: See  J.W. Gray, Formal Category Theory 1: Adjointness for 2-Categories LNM 391, &7). THese are treated (with different name) in  "Cohomologie non abélienne" (J.Giraud), ch.II.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The oplax limit is the category of sections** for the functor from the Grothendieck construction to the base category.

The **strong** limit is the category of **cartesian sections** (every arrow in the base category gets mapped to a cartesian one).

Notice how this goes along very well with the interpretation as dependent product and as $\forall$: The set theoretic product is just the set of sections into the disjoint union.

**[edit]**

Given a strong functor $F:X\to\mathrm{Cat}$ we denote the Grothendieck construction by
$$\mathrm{Gr}(F).$$
There is a canonical functor $\pi:\mathrm{Gr}(F)\to X$. Sections of this functor are functors
$$s:X\to\mathrm{Gr}(F)$$
such that $s\circ\pi=\mathrm{id}$.

So even more explicitely a section amounts to

forall $x\in X$ an object $s_x\in F(x)$ and ...

Comment: Is there an explicit description (describing the objects and morphisms) of the category of sections somewhere?

Comment: I edited my answer and added further explanations

Comment: @JasonGross, this question was answered in more detail before (see Mike's answer and my explanation): http://mathoverflow.net/questions/164343/what-is-the-co-form-of-grothendieck-construction